# Mount prometheus data to host volume /mnt/resources/

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, prometheus

I am running prometheus using docker run command but unfortunate i am unable to mount the /mnt/data volume to the prometheus data inside the container. Can any one help me how do i use my host mount point /mnt/data for prometheus to store Timeseries data instead of the default docker /var/lib/docker/volume/container/prometheus/data/.

Here is my docker run command:

```docker run -d --name prometheus -p 9090:9090 -v /DATA/prometheus/etc/:/etc/prometheus -v /DATA/prometheus/etc/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml``